# Redirecting output only on a successful command call

Tags: shell-script, shell, io-redirection, posix

I want to redirect the output of a command (`diff` in this case) to a file but only if there is a difference in files I'm comparing. For example, imagine I have three files `a`, `b`, and `c` where `a` and `b` are equivalent but `a` and `c` are not.

If I do `diff a c > output.txt` or `diff a b > output.txt`, regardless of whether there is a difference or not, `output.txt` will be created. I only want `output.txt` to be created if there is a diff (i.e, diff returns 1).

I'd want to do something like:

```
if ! diff a c > /dev/null; then
    diff a c > output.txt
fi
```

But without running the command twice. I *could* save the contents of the command like so:

```
res=$(diff a c)
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "$res" > output.txt
fi
```

But then I'm bringing `echo` into this as a "middle-man", which could potentially raise some issues. How can I redirect output/create a file only if there's output without duplicating code?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the `echo` solution

Comment: @Jesse_b I guess I'm being paranoid because of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618696/shell-write-variable-contents-to-a-file/49418265). While the issues shown here won't really be evident in my example (using `diff`), it could fail for other commands. I could use the `printf` solution, but I was just wondering if there was any way to avoid saving to a variable and immediately printing it afterwards

Comment: Yeah if you want to avoid that issue you could use `printf` or `echo --` to specify the end of options.  You could also use `cat`.

Comment: A simple temporary file? Delete it if not needed or copy in place if needed.

Comment: You need to save the output somewhere, if you want to conditionally discard it. Please edit the question to clarify the issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could call the command once, redirect the output, then remove the output if there were no differences:

```
diff a c > output.txt && rm output.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

`diff` is a relatively expensive command, at least if the files are different. Calculating a minimal set of changes is (relatively) CPU intensive. So its understandable not to want to do that twice.

`cmp`, however, is cheap, CPU-wise. Presuming these files are of a reasonable size (I doubt you'd call diff on multi-GB files), it will have almost no performance cost—and might even be quicker in the files identical case.

```bash
if ! cmp -s a c; then # -s = silent, do not print results to console
    diff a c > output.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

What about temporary file?

```
diff a c > /tmp/output.txt
if [ $? != 0 ]; then mv /tmp/output.txt /my/folder/output.txt; else rm -f /tmp/output.txt; fi
```

replace the `-f` with `-i` if you want delete confirmation dialog.

This way you only run command twice, no temporary variables and no 'middleman' be it echo, printf or anything else.